# How to add a component multiple times?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton h = new JButton("HELLO");
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    panel.add(h);
}
```

For some reason the panel just shows the button one time.

Answer (score 7):

You can't add the same instance of an object 15 times. You need to create 15 objects:

```
panel.add(h);
```

Should be:

```
panel.add( new JButton("Hello " + i) );
```